# Onion Ring Chart with nested elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

I'm new to D3.js, but have JS programming experience. I am attempting to create a chart and I have the somewhat scaffolding of what I need (using a standard sunburst chart), but I need each layer to have nested elements within it and am struggling to get my head around what I need to do.

This
[Onion Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etx2w.png) graphic represents what I am trying to achieve. I have searched for 'onion chart + d3' but haven't come across any examples.

I would really appreciate any pointers, or even better, some pre-existing code base I could build on. Thank you.

[image: Onion Diagram]

EDIT 1:
I've managed to get something close to what I want. I've used a D3 pack chart with circles. The issue I'm having is aligning the circles. In the attached screenshot, I would like;

- 'C' and 'A' to hug the circle just like 'B' (so 'C' is above 'B' and 'A' is below 'B'
- and once done, have 'B' and it's child 'B' circles to align horizontally (rather than the angle they are currently running)

I realise I need to edit the 'transform' attribute of each 'leaf-node' but unsure about how I go about this programmatically. Below is my current code. And below that what I am trying to achieve.

**Currently working in D3.js**
[image: Current working visualisation]

**What I'm trying to achieve***
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
  var margin = 20,
      diameter = 700;

  var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-1, 5])
      .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

  var pack = d3.layout.pack()
      .padding(2)
      .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; })

  var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

  d3.json("data.json", function(error, root) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);

    var focus = root,
        nodes = pack.nodes(root),
        view;

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
        .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

    var text = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
        .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? null : "none"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


    // Adding Rect to each child circle
    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
        .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? null : "none"; })
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return 200; });

    var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

    d3.select(".container")
        .style("background", color(-1))
        .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

    zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

    function zoom(d) {
      var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

      var transition = d3.transition()
          .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
          .tween("zoom", function(d) {
            var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
            return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
          });

      transition.selectAll("text")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
          .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
          .each("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
          .each("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
    }

    function zoomTo(v) {
      var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
      circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
    }
  });

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

```
{
  "name": "data",
  "children": 
  [
    {"name": "food", "size": 30,
      "children": 
      [
        {"name": "A", "size": 40},
        {"name": "B", "size": 40},
        {"name": "C", "size": 40},
        {"name": "apple", "size": 40,
          "children": 
          [
            {"name": "A2", "size": 40},
            {"name": "B2", "size": 40},
            {"name": "C3", "size": 40},
            {"name": "green", "size": 40,
              "children": 
              [
                {"name": "A2", "size": 40},
                {"name": "B2", "size": 40},
                {"name": "C3", "size": 40},
                {"name": "granny smith", "size": 40,
                  "children": 
                  [
                    {"name": "A2", "size": 40},
                    {"name": "B2", "size": 40},
                    {"name": "C3", "size": 40},
                    {"name": "price", "size": 40,
                      "children": 
                      [
                        {"name": "A2", "size": 40},
                        {"name": "B2", "size": 40},
                        {"name": "C3", "size": 40},
                        {"name": "1.99", "size": 40,
                          "children": 
                          [
                            {"name": "End1", "size": 40},
                            {"name": "End2", "size": 40},
                            {"name": "End3", "size": 40}
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.bar {
  display: none;
}
.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Since D3 is "Data Driven Documents", could you add your input data please? Also, are the little people images important?, if so, we need to add these to the data and then work them into the answer (shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: Cleanup up the math and the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/29nMq.png / https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/xxZdNWb

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example, as a starting point, with d3.js v5:

(Also in codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/xxZdNWb)

Note, you don't necessarily need to "nest" svg elements, as they paint in the order they appear in the DOM, so you see here, I just appended each circle after each other and each subsequent one, paints over the previous (i.e. pseudo gets a larger z-index).

Are the little people images important?, if so, we need to add these to the data and then work them in to the answer (shouldn't be too hard).

```js
const myData = [
  { color: "red" },
  { color: "aqua" },
  { color: "orange" },
  { color: "blue" },
  { color: "green" }
];
const width = 100;
const [svg_width, svg_height] = [250, 200];
const len = myData.length;
const padding_bottom = 3;

d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(".onion")
  .data(myData.reverse())
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "onion")
  .attr("fill", (d) => d.color)
  .attr("cx", svg_width / 2)
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - i);
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const padd = padding_bottom * i;
    return svg_height / 2 + diff - padd;
  })
  .attr("r", (d, i) => (width / len) * (len - i));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="target" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 250 200">
</svg>
```

Output:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 29-Jun-20:**

```js
const myData = [
  { color: "red", children: ["A"] },
  { color: "aqua", children: ["A", "B"] },
  { color: "orange", children: ["A", "B", "C"] },
  { color: "blue", children: ["A", "B", "C", "D"] },
  { color: "green", children: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] }
];
const width = 100;
const [svg_width, svg_height] = [250, 200];
const len = myData.length;
const padding_bottom = 3;
const padding_top = 2;
const arc = (120 * Math.PI) / 180;

const layers = d3
  .select("svg")
  .selectAll(".onion")
  .data(myData.reverse())
  .enter()
  .append("g");

layers
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "onion")
  .attr("fill", (d) => d.color)
  .attr("cx", svg_width / 2)
  .attr("cy", (d, i) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - i);
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const padd = padding_bottom * i;
    return svg_height / 2 + diff - padd;
  })
  .attr("r", (d, i) => (width / len) * (len - i));

const persons = layers
  .selectAll(".person")
  .data((d, i) =>
    d.children.map((e) => ({ item: e, i, len: d.children.length }))
  );

persons
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "person")
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("cx", (d, j) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - d.i);
    const cr = ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5;
    const sep = width / len;
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const center = svg_width / 2;
    const r2 = r - cr - padding_top;
    //console.log(d);
    if (d.len == 1) return center;
    const theta = (arc / (d.len - 1)) * j - arc / 2;
    return center + r2 * Math.sin(theta);
  })
  .attr("cy", (d, j) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - d.i);
    const cr = ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5;
    const sep = width / len;
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const padd = padding_bottom * d.i;
    const center = svg_height / 2 + diff - padd;
    const r2 = r - cr - padding_top;
    if (d.len == 1) return center - r2;
    const theta = (arc / (d.len - 1)) * j - arc / 2;
    return center - Math.abs(r2 * Math.cos(theta));
  })
  .attr("r", (d, j) => ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5);

persons
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "person-name")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("x", (d, j) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - d.i);
    const cr = ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5;
    const sep = width / len;
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const center = svg_width / 2;
    const r2 = r - cr - padding_top;
    //console.log(d);
    if (d.len == 1) return center;
    const theta = (arc / (d.len - 1)) * j - arc / 2;
    return center + r2 * Math.sin(theta);
  })
  .attr("y", (d, j) => {
    const r = (width / len) * (len - d.i);
    const cr = ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5;
    const sep = width / len;
    const diff = svg_height / 2 - r;
    const padd = padding_bottom * d.i;
    const center = svg_height / 2 + diff - padd;
    const r2 = r - cr - padding_top;
    if (d.len == 1) return center - r2;
    const theta = (arc / (d.len - 1)) * j - arc / 2;
    return center - Math.abs(r2 * Math.cos(theta));
  })
  .html((d, j) => d.item)
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", (d, j) => ((width / len) * (len - d.i + 1) * 1.0) ** 0.5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="target" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 250 200">
</svg>
```

Output:

[image]

Math / Trig:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Alex. This is similar to where I have got. The 'people' are necessary, which is the part I have been struggling with. In my case, they actually represent individual names, and just need to be rendered as circles within the relevant parent 'color' circle. 

I'll take a closer look at your code today and see if I can build on it to how I need. I appreciate your time to post the demo and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty close, I did the trigonometry on a piece of paper, now just need to translate to code.

Comment: @GaelicAU If my answer solved your problem, please consider to mark as accepted and up-vote. Thanks